# Django script configuration for beat mode

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

Below is my current /etc/init.d/celeryd script:

```
# Name of nodes to start, here we have a single node
#CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# or we could have three nodes:
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/srv/project/website"

# How to call "manage.py celeryd_multi"
CELERYD_MULTI="$CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"

# How to call "manage.py celeryctl"
CELERYCTL="$CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryctl"

# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/srv/project/logs/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/srv/project/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="root"
CELERYD_GROUP="root"

# Name of the projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="website.settings"
```

I now want to run Periodic Tasks, adding to/changing  my example above how to I create the script configuration for beat mode?

Do I just add the following to the file? and what is the last line?

```
# Where the Django project is.
CELERYBEAT_CHDIR="/srv/project/website"

# Name of the projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="website.settings"

# Path to celerybeat
CELERYBEAT="/opt/project/website/manage.py celerybeat"

# Extra arguments to celerybeat
CELERYBEAT_OPTS="--schedule=/var/run/celerybeat-schedule"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add it to the bottom of the script or create a new one that your init script points to.